# The HTTP verb POST used to access path ' ' is not allowed on IIS 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a Bit new on this ..I am Replicating this Demo Example on my Local Server

http://www.bibeault.org/jqia2/chapter4/dvds/dvds.html

In Live Example Resulting data gets properly loaded ..But Not on My Machine ..My Code and css are exactly same ,

**Update** : Recently Tracked error :

```
>POST http://localhost:1701/applyFilters 405 Method Not Allowed<br/>
```

> The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/applyFilters' is not allowed.

it is on .Net Server.... resulting data comes from this Page http://www.bibeault.org/jqia2/chapter4/dvds/applyFilters ... Do I need to completely recreate this page on My server also ?..Need some guidence

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DVD Ambassador &mdash; Disc Locator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/dvds.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var filterCount = 0;

        $(function () {

            $('#addFilterButton').click(function () {
                var filterItem = $('<div>')
            .addClass('filterItem')
            .appendTo('#filterPane')
            .data('suffix', '.' + (filterCount++));

                $('div.template.filterChooser')
                .children().clone().appendTo(filterItem)
              .trigger('adjustName');
            });

            $('select.filterChooser').live('change', function () {
                var filterType = $(':selected', this).attr('data-filter-type');
                var filterItem = $(this).closest('.filterItem');
                $('.qualifier', filterItem).remove();
                $('div.template.' + filterType)
              .children().clone().addClass('qualifier')
              .appendTo(filterItem)
              .trigger('adjustName');
                $('option[value=""]', this).remove();
            });

            $('button.filterRemover').live('click', function () {
                $(this).closest('div.filterItem').remove();
            });

            $('.filterItem [name]').live('adjustName', function () {
                var suffix = $(this).closest('.filterItem').data('suffix');
                if (/(\w)+\.(\d)+$/.test($(this).attr('name'))) return;
                $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + suffix);
            });

            $('#addFilterButton').click();

            $('#filtersForm').submit(function () {
                $('#resultsPane').load('applyFilters', $('#filtersForm').serializeArray());
                return false;
            });

            /* bonus exercise code -- uncomment to enable
            $('input.numeric').live('keypress',function(event){
            if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) return false;
            });
            */
        });
    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pageContent">

      <h1>DVD Ambassador</h1>
      <h2>Disc Locator</h2>

      <form id="filtersForm" action="/fetchFilteredResults" method="post">

        <fieldset id="filtersPane">
          <legend>Filters</legend>
          <div id="filterPane"></div>
          <div class="buttonBar">
            <button type="button" id="addFilterButton">Add Filter</button>
            <button type="submit" id="applyFilterButton">Apply Filters</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>

        <div id="resultsPane"><span class="none">No results displayed</span></div>

      </form>

    </div>

    <!-- hidden templates -->
    <div id="templates">

      <div class="template filterChooser">
        <button type="button" class="filterRemover" title="Remove this filter">X</button>

        <select name="filter" class="filterChooser" title="Select a property to filter">
          <option value="" data-filter-type="" selected="selected">-- choose a filter --</option>
          <option value="title" data-filter-type="stringMatch">DVD Title</option>
          <option value="category" data-filter-type="stringMatch">Category</option>
          <option value="binder" data-filter-type="numberRange">Binder</option>
          <option value="release" data-filter-type="dateRange">Release Date</option>
          <option value="viewed" data-filter-type="boolean">Viewed?</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="template stringMatch">
        <select name="stringMatchType">
          <option value="*">contains</option>
          <option value="^">starts with</option>
          <option value="$">ends with</option>
          <option value="=">is exactly</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="term"/>
      </div>

      <div class="template numberRange">
        <input type="text" name="numberRange1" class="numeric"/> <span>through</span>
        <input type="text" name="numberRange2" class="numeric"/>
      </div>

      <div class="template dateRange">
        <input type="text" name="dateRange1" class="dateValue"/> <span>through</span>
        <input type="text" name="dateRange2" class="dateValue"/>
      </div>

      <div class="template boolean">
        <input type="radio" name="booleanFilter" value="true" checked="checked"/> <span>Yes</span>
        <input type="radio" name="booleanFilter" value="false"/> <span>No</span>
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

My Css:

```
body {
  background-image: url(backg.jpg);
}

body,td,th {
  font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

#templates {
  display:none; 
}

#pageContent {
  width: 720px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #444444;
  border: 2px ridge #888888;
  margin: 32px auto;
  padding: 8px 32px;
}

h1,h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1,h2,h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset,legend {
  border: 2px ridge silver;
}

fieldset {
  padding-top: 12px;
}

legend {
  padding: 3px 12px;
  background-color: silver;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#filterPane {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.filterItem * {
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

#resultsPane {
  margin-top: 14px;
}

#resultsPane span.none{
  color: silver;
  font-style: italic;
}

#resultsPane table {
  background-color: #444444;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

#resultsPane th {
  background-color: silver;
  border: 2px outset silver;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

#resultsPane td {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1px 12px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: center;
}

#resultsPane td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

input.numeric {
  width: 48px;
}

input.dateValue {
  width: 64px;
}
```

---

#### Solved

This was just needed to add in web.config for IIS7

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="htm" path="*.htm" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule"  scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="Either" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Everybody suggestion and this post helped:

http://zhongchenzhou.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/iis-7-7-5-allow-post-requests-to-html-files/

Comment: What is your server stack (php? .Net?). You need to have mapped the URL `/applyFilters` to your code somehow. Did you mean to specify a particular server page?

Comment: it is on .Net ... I am a bit new on this .... resulting data comes from this Page http://www.bibeault.org/jqia2/chapter4/dvds/applyFilters ... Do you mean to complete recreate this on My server ..?

Comment: Does the applyFilters page exist on your local server or do you mean to access the one on your live server?

Comment: No .. i was trying to access it from live example server

Comment: I have tried this .. But it is showing 405 error

Comment: Those samples appear to be running on an Apache server and not IIS, so you will need to change your Visual Studio project (which is based on that project) to provide equivalent route mapping.

Comment: can you please elaborate more How can i achieve this

Comment: Answer added below. Just rename the data file as a quick fix. You can't have files without extensions under IIS (by default).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running some kind of development server: The server does not allow POST requests. Try to deploy your code on a *real* server and it should work.

Someone had similar problems and it was the VisualStudio Development server which caused the problem (http://www.mojoportal.com/Forums/Thread.aspx?pageid=5&t=6383~-1).

At the moment applyFilters is accessed on your local server. You could try:

```
$('#resultsPane').load('http://url.to.other.server/applyFilters', $('#filtersForm').serializeArray());
```

But then you have cross-site scripting. You should use a local version of applyFilters (and allow POST requests).

It seems like IIS does not allow POST requests on HTML files: https://serverfault.com/a/349193/133535

Comment: yes . my server is also VisualStudio Development server

Comment: I created applyFilter.html Page ...publish my pages on IIS instead of visual studio server. still it has showing same 405 error ..please suggest

Comment: I tried  $('#resultsPane').load('/jqia2/chapter4/dvds/applyFilters', $('#filtersForm').serializeArray()); .... But still same error ... Whats mean by having local version of /applyfilter page ..I created applyFilter.html Page and tried to access it .. still it doesnt change error

Comment: If your html file is called applyFilter.html then you can't access it by .../apllyFilters. But if the error is still the 405, then your IIS does not allow POST requests. Sorry, can't help with IIS itself.

Comment: my url on IIS is http://localhost/WebApplication2/applyFilters.htm ..it is properly accesible in my browser ..i pasted complete path in code ...still it is giving 405 error

Comment: It's an Apache server demo, and the data feed is just a file (without an extension), so IIS will not allow access by default.

Comment: Solved ..thanks ..posting my effort in original post

Answer (score 0):

Basically that demo is running on an Apache server, not under IIS. The dvd list at `http://www.bibeault.org/jqia2/chapter4/dvds/applyFilters` is only a file **with no extension**.

if you browser one level above `http://www.bibeault.org/jqia2/chapter4/dvds/` you can see the file list.

The quick fix is to rename it to a `applyFilters.html` on your local version and change the `load` reference.

The alternative is to allow files without extensions to be loaded under IIS (which is off by default for security reasons).